# Best source of info on PID controllers for quadrotor UAVs

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

Which is the best source of info for PID controllers for quadrotor UAVs.

Thanks.

Nick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64568/best-source-of-info-on-pid-controllers-for-quadrotor-uavs/) by [nickothieno](https://answers.ros.org/users/5085/nickothieno/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Go to http://www.sfly.org/publications .There you can find some latest papers and journals on quadrotor UAV. There is a ROS package tum_ardrone which has implementation of PID on quadrotor.

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0